# Solve the congruence $M^{49}\equiv 2\pmod{19}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

> Solve the congruence $M^{49}\equiv 2\pmod{19}$.

I don't know how to solve this one. I can get it down to $M^{13}\equiv 2$ using Fermat's little theorem, but after that I'm stumped.

Comment: Then also $M^{18}\equiv1\pmod{19}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown OP knows that. FLT ...

Comment: @DonThousand Funny enough, FLT is an abbreviation that could stand for either of Fermat's theorems.

Comment: @Gae.S. Haha true, although I don't know any problems that apply both.

Comment: @DonThousand I don't think the OP has taken it fully to heart though.

Comment: Note that $13^{-1}\equiv 7\pmod 18$. What happens if you raise both sides of your simplified congruence to the $7$th power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve the Diophantine equation $18x+49y = 1$ and take the smallest positive solution for $y$.  This turns out to be $y = 7$.  Raise both sides of your congruence to the $7$ power

$$(M^{49})^7 \equiv 2^7 \pmod{19}.$$

Now you know that $49\cdot 7 \equiv 1 \pmod{18}$ so you have

$$M^1 \equiv 2^7 \equiv 14 \pmod{19}.$$

Comment: How did mod 18 enter into it? Why are we allowed to count modulo 18 in the exponent?

Comment: @Peatherfed  Didn't you use little Fermat in the statement of your question?  $18 = 19 -1.$

Comment: That's true, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

*(Note that I am assuming that $M^{49}$ in the question refers to the $49$th Mersenne number i.e. $M^{49}=2^{49}-1$).*

You can use FLT, but here is an alternative approach:

We want to show the $2^{49}-1 \equiv 2 \mod 19$, which is the same as $2^{49} \equiv 3 \mod 19$.

We have:

$2^2 \equiv 4 \mod 19
\\2^4 = (2^2)^2 \equiv 4^2 \equiv -3 \mod 19
\\2^8 = (2^4)^2 \equiv (-3)^2 \equiv 9 \mod 19
\\2^{16} = (2^8)^2 \equiv 9^2 \equiv 81 \equiv 5 \mod 19
\\2^{32} = (2^{16})^2 \equiv 5^2 \equiv 25 \equiv 6 \mod 19$

and also $49 = 32 + 16 + 1$ so

$2^{49} = 2^{32} \times 2^{16} \times 2$

I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: Still, given that $M^{49}\equiv 2^{49}-1$, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @Peatherfed Once you know $2^{49} \mod 19$, then finding $2^{49}-1 \mod 19$ is simple.

Comment: Sure, it's 2, but how does that help? I'm sorry if I seem dumb, I just don't see how it helps.

Comment: @Peatherfed $M^{49}=2^{49}-1 = 2^{32} \times 2^{16} \times 2 -1$. You know the values of all the parts of the right hand side modulo $19$ so you just have to put them together.

Comment: But how does that help finding $M$?

Comment: I am assuming that $M^{49}$ in the question stands for the $49$th Mersenne number i.e. $M^{49}=2^{49}-1$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $2$ is a primitive element modulo $19$.  To show this, observe that $\phi(19)=18$.  If $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $2^k\equiv 1\pmod{19}$, then $k$ is a divisor of $18$.  Since $2^k<19$ for $k<5$, we need to only check whether $k=6$ or $k=9$ works, but it is easily seen that none of them works.

Let $M\equiv 2^r\pmod{19}$ for some integer $r$, $0\leq r<18$.  We get
$$2^{13r}\equiv M^{13}\equiv M^{49}\equiv 2\pmod{19}$$
implies that
$$13r\equiv 1\pmod{18}.$$
This can be easily solved.

> That is, $5r\equiv -13r\equiv -1 \equiv 35\pmod{18}$, making $r\equiv 7\pmod{18}$.  Thus, $M\equiv 2^7\equiv14\pmod{19}$.